# Call URL and receive response URL

Tags: t-sql, url, cmd

I want to call a URL, which redirects me to another URL, which I need to get as a response/return from my call (the URL2). I am looking for a MSSQL solution (I know there is a potential risk and should no do that...) and/or CMD script. For instance:

URL 1: http://www.wikipedia.com

returns

URL 2: https://www.wikipedia.org

I want to call URL1 and receive URL2.

Comment: How does this have to do with TSQL?  Are you wanting a lookup list table for redirects and how that would work?

Comment: No. I want to generate URL 1 from SQL. If there are more redirects on the way, I want just the target URL.